# How to run lxc exec for commands with pipe?

Tags: bash, shell-script, pipe, lxc

for example, I have this command:

```
lxc launch ubuntu:18.04 memsql1
lxc exec memsql1 -- wget -O - 'https://release.memsql.com/release-aug2018.gpg'  2>/dev/null | sudo apt-key add - && apt-key list
lxc exec memsql1 apt-cache policy apt-transport-https
lxc exec memsql1 -- apt -y install apt-transport-https
lxc exec memsql1 -- echo "deb [arch=amd64] https://release.memsql.com/production/debian memsql main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/memsql.list
```

^ the command above (2nd and last line) will pipe into host instead of container. I know that I can use `lxc exec memsql1 bash` then run the command inside bash, but I want to make script out of these commands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nevermind, found it:

```
lxc exec memsql1 -- bash -c "the command with | pipe"
```

Comment: Also works for scripts like `lxc exec vm1 -- bash -c "./stuff.sh"`